# How to groupby in subquery SQL

Tags: sql, subquery

I have the following query:

```
SELECT "IMPORTACIONCOLUMN3", "role", COUNT("IMPORTACIONCOLUMN1")
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE ID = 9
GROUP BY "IMPORTACIONCOLUMN3", "role"
```

This gives me the following result:

[image]

I would like to achieve the following:

1. The "unique" values are grouped together (i.e. Instead of having 4 values of "Robot 1" these are grouped togehter in just 1 cell summing the count values.
2. The second group by or subquery has to be the same count, but with role instead of "IMPORTACIONCOLUM3"
3. Is it possible (for the second picture) to "link" the values either by index or adding an extra column to reference them (i.e. There's two "Solicitante" with a count value of "52" but it refers to "Robot 1" and other to "Solicitante" with count value of "58" links to "Robot 2"

The second image represent visually what I'm trying to explain.

[image]

I have been trying on my own but only have reached the following:

```
select "IMPORTACIONCOLUMN3", count("IMPORTACIONCOLUMN1")
from
(
   select "IMPORTACIONCOLUMN1", count("role"), "IMPORTACIONCOLUMN3"
   from MYTABLE 
   WHERE ID = 9
   group by "IMPORTACIONCOLUMN1", "IMPORTACIONCOLUMN3"
) as tmp
group by "IMPORTACIONCOLUMN3"
```

[image]

But it is not yet the result I am looking for.

Thanks in advance for your help and tips!

EDIT:

Explaining my desired output in detail
Each one of "Robot 1, 2, 3" have roles such as "Solicitante", "Gerente", etc. with different values.

i.e. The first row "Humano" value "243" is the sum of "Agente de Compras - 95", "Gerente Financiero - 37", "Gerente Solicitante - 45", "Proovedor - 31", "Solicitante - 60".
I am linking these by the column "GRAFICOCOLUMNARECURSIVOID" with contains the index of whatever "Robot" these "roles" are from.

I would like to achieve a query containing subquerys that allows me to have this output.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this for question number 1:

```
SELECT "IMPORTACIONCOLUMN3", COUNT("IMPORTACIONCOLUMN1")
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE ID = 9
GROUP BY "IMPORTACIONCOLUMN3"
```

the problem is Role: Robot 1 have 4 roles

and this for question 2:

```
SELECT "role", COUNT("IMPORTACIONCOLUMN1")
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE ID = 9
GROUP BY "role"
```

Question 3, I don't understand what you are asking for. Please make an example.

Comment: Hello, I have added an EDIT section at the end of the post explaining more in detail, thanks!

Comment: What you want is to mix two different column(with meaning) in one. I think I can't accomplish something like that.